# Hover over element changes element which is then included in hover over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Excuse the phrasing of the title but it was kind of hard to sum up.

This is what I want to do

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
<div id="example1" style="display:none;">Test</div>
<div id="example2" style="display:none;">Test</div>
```

When `#test` is hovered over, it causes `#example1` and `#exmaple2` to become visible and then when hovering discontinues, `#example1` and `#exmaple2` return to being invisible again.

Simple code obviously.

```
$('#test').hover(
  function () {
    $('#example1,#example2').show();
  }, 
  function () {
   $('#example1,#example2').hide();
  }
);
```

Now here's the dilemma. I need `#example1` and `#exmaple2` to remain visible when hovered over, this is not possible because when the mouse leaves `#test` to go hover over `#example1` or `#example2`, they go back to being invisible, as the code above instructs it to do. How can I make this possible?

I understand wrapping the elements together like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="test">Test</div>
 <div id="example1" style="display:none;">Test</div>
 <div id="example2" style="display:none;">Test</div>
</div>
```

and changing the code to

```
$('#wrapper').hover(
  function () {
    $('#example1,#example2').show();
  }, 
  function () {
   $('#example1,#example2').hide();
  }
);
```

would fix this, but I'm not able to do so because in my actual code, `#test` is already under a wrapper, a wrapper that has a very specific design associated with it that would be destroyed if I included `#example1` and `#example2` in it.

To sum up the above, my question is: When `#test` is hovered over and `#example1` and `#example2` become visible, how can I keep `#example1` and `#example2` visible even when leaving `#test` to hover over `#example1` and `#example2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't do the job?

```
$('#test').hover(
  function () {
    $('#example1,#example2').show();
  }
  , function () {
    $('#example1,#example2').hide();
  }
);
```

Then alter your html to something like this to solve the height problem.

```
<div id="test">
Test
<div id="example1" style="display:none;z-index:256;">Test</div>
<div id="example2" style="display:none;z-index:256;">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I stated above, I already have `#test` in a different wrapper in my code, it's height-specific so `#example1` and `#example2` would ruin it. I'm trying to see if there's any way to do it in jQuery or JavaScript before having to redo my entire code.

Comment: @Odyssey I've added the other half of the solution.

Comment: This gave me the idea of `position:absolute` and `margin-top` which works just like I need it!

Answer (score 0):

how about using mousenter and mouseleave ???

EDIT...
you can include the elements

```
$('#test,#example1,#example2').hover(

function() {
    $('#example1,#example2').show();
}, function() {
    $('#example1,#example2').hide();
});
```

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` is essentially `.hover` in jQuery, which still brings me back to my original dilemma which is not being able to wrap `#test`, `#example1`, and `#example2` together due to preexisting code.